# leveled::DB::Open() undefined after I installed leveldb and snappy, macOS

Tags: c++, leveldb

I want to verify the leveldb installation. I have a main function only containing `levelDB::DB::Open()` function. I installed both snappy and leveldb by using `brew install`. I have boost 1.67 installed too. I have GCC 8.1. I am running macOS 10.13.5.

my source file looks like this:

```
int main(void) {
    leveldb::DB *db;
    leveldb::Options options;
    options.create_if_missing = true;
    auto err = leveldb::DB::Open(options, "../tmpDB", &db);
    if (err.ok()) {
        std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
    }else {
        std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
    }
    delete db;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile my code I use `g++ main.cpp -lleveldb -lsnappy -o test`. The compiler generate the error like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "leveldb::DB::Open(leveldb::Options const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, leveldb::DB**)", referenced from:
      _main in ccYcksfh.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I solve this link error?

Answer (score 0):

You can install leveldb with compiler version.

```
brew reinstall leveldb --cc=gcc-4.8
```

[Can't link against leveldb on OSX](https://github.com/google/leveldb/issues/331)